# Barbalat's Lemma Proof Typo and Clarification

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, adaptive-control

I am trying to study the proof of Barbalat's Lemma by Hao Liu as shown in [this link](https://mathpost.asu.edu/~hliu/Things2Explain/Barbalat's%20lemma.pdf)

However, I realized that there is a typo in there:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(t_n + \delta \right)- f\left(t_n\right)\right| = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|f\left(t_n + \delta \right)- \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(t_n\right)\right|$$

Shouldn't it be:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(t_n + \delta \right)- f\left(t_n\right)\right| = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(t_n + \delta \right)\right|- \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(t_n\right)\right|$$

Also, why is the second equation valid? Can one give me a proof of that?

Answer (score 2):

There are three typos in the line:

- The limit should be as $n \to \infty$, not as $t\to\infty$.
- There is not a missing bar - there is an extra bar.
- The next step should be $|\alpha - \alpha|$, not $|\alpha| - |\alpha|$.

The line should be 
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|f(t_n + \delta)- f(t_n)\right| &= \left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(f(t_n + \delta)- f(t_n)\big)\right|
\\ &= \left|\lim_{n\to\infty} f(t_n + \delta)- \lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)\right|\\ &=|\alpha - \alpha| \\ &= 0\end{align}$$

The interchange of $|\phantom{x}|$ and limit is justified because the absolute value is continuous.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right)\right| \geq \left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right) -f\left(t_n\right)\right| + \left|f\left(t_n\right)\right|$?

Comment: No. The triangle inequality is $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$. Look carefully.

Comment: Ok, got it, but it should be $\left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right)\right| - \left|f\left(t_n\right)\right| \leq \left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right) - f\left(t_n\right)\right|$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right) - f\left(t_n\right)\right| \geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|f\left(t_n + \delta\right)\right| - \left|f\left(t_n\right)\right|$

Comment: The triangle inequality is $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$. I expected that you could figure out how to subtract $|f(t_n)|$ from both sides without my having to hold your hand.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the inequality be flipped? I think you made a mistake in your original answer for the inequality.

Comment: You are right. I guess I was more tired than I thought Saturday. After examining the proof again, I believe I have the correct interpretation now. They were not using an inequality after all.